# Adding jar files to plugin dependency

Tags: osgi, bundle

please tell me how to add jars to plug in dependencies in OSGi bundle??I tried by using,plugins--configure build path---add new jars(but I can't add )

Answer (score 1):

Add them in the root of your bundle, and in the MANIFEST.MF editor add the in the  bundle classpath (or Bundle-Classpath: line in the file itself).

Comment: What is root of the bundle??